# How to migrate a DB from Fox Pro to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-migration, foxpro

i have to move mi DB from Fox Pro to Mysql. So i want to know how to migrate the data to a new one and if the data can be refresh automatically. I have a software ERP that uses Fox Pro but wanna move that DB to Mysql to be able to use in google.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. Could you explain what you mean by "use in Google"? Do you mean you'd like to host things on Google's *cloud servers*? Does your ERP software even *work* with MySQL?

Comment: the software i am using use Fox pro and store the data in my local server, so i want to use that data in google (Google Data Studio) but google does not support Fox pro, so i need to move the db to mysql or sql to be able to link the db with google

Comment: You'll have to find some sort of converter, then. This isn't likely to be a simple task.

Comment: If you can export the data into a csv file, you can [load that into Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7333350?hl=en).

Comment: i need to do that taks automatically, like if someone use the software and add new info to fox pro then the mysql db also update with that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that you need to consider is what Application language you will be using for your ERP system.

If you plan to continue with your ERP system in the Visual Foxpro language, then YES you can move where the data is stored and retrieved from.
BUT you will also have to change the Application code such that it can access the data in a different manner (via ODBC) in its new location, modify it accordingly, and then write it back. That involves a good number of changes to the Application itself.
However once those changes are made to the Application you can work quite well with a different, non-'native' data 'back end'.

However, if you are throwing out the VFP ERP system and replacing it with a totally new Application (Google Data Studio??), then - Sure you can move the data, but you will also most likely have to totally develop/redevelop the new Application since it is most likely not "looking" for its data in the same data tables & data fields used for the VFP Application.
To do that task you will need to COMPLETELY understand EVERYTHING that the current ERP system is doing with the data within ALL of its separate functional parts so that you can replicate it in the new language's Application.

Even if you are only going to use Google Data Studio for online reports, you will still need to COMPLETELY understand how the VFP ERP Application is storing data so that it can be extracted for reports.
* Is it using Related tables? If they used good data Normalization - Most assuredly.  If so, do you know which ones and how the multiple tables might be related?
* Is the data somehow/somewhere encrypted?  If so, do you know how to decrypt it?
* There are MANY things to understand before leaping to another solution.

Good Luck